# Virtualization mini-project

Tags: c#, java, project, virtualization

I have spent some time reading wiki and Virtual Machines by James Smith and Ravi Nair.

I know that Virtualization is (in layman's term) enacting the behaviour or performance of something.

Now it so happens that I have to make a presentation on virtualization technology. I will have to implement a small working model also.

I am a decent Java coder with experience in C#.NET, JSP, ASP.NET, Ruby, Perl and MSSql. Virtualization is very much new to me. Hence I don't know which tools to use, what material to refer(for practicals) and so on.

My interest is anything that has a good coding-knowledge requirement. I would love to do something in Java or C#. Can anyone please suggest a project that can be achieved by a team of 2 in around two months?

Comment: Virtualize a 16bit processor! ...college, those were the days!

Comment: @Prescott: i8051 or i4004 will be much simpler than most (if not all) 16-bit CPUs. But one needs to have software written for the CPU of choice or else there will be nothing to show. And the demo needs to show the benefits of virtualization, it shouldn't be just emulation for the sake of emulation.

Comment: Is asking for an advise not constructive?